# How to handle two forms on one page for validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two forms that get displayed alternatively in a popup, one for editing (which is loaded by ajax), one for creation.

I want to use jquery validation to display hints both on editing and on submission of fields.

Some of the validation involves time spans which must not overlap.

This works for creation, but the new rule I am creating for editing does not get triggered because the rule for creation takes precedence.

I have added class rules, because the rules I created by name or id somehow don't get active at all, maybe because I am confused how the jquery validate plugin works. These rules are commented out in the code snippet.

```
var classRules = {};

classRules['thresholdStartTime'] = {};
classRules['thresholdStartTime'][globalThresholdCheckName] = $form
classRules['thresholdEndTime'] = {};
classRules['thresholdEndTime'][globalThresholdCheckName] = $form

/*
 * 
 for(var q = 0; q<20; ++q) {
    validationrules['thresholdStartTime' + q] = {};
    validationrules['thresholdStartTime' + q]['required'] = true;
    validationrules['thresholdStartTime' + q][globalThresholdCheckName] = $form

    validationrules['thresholdEndTime' + q] = {};
    validationrules['thresholdEndTime' + q]['required'] = true;
    validationrules['thresholdEndTime' + q][globalThresholdCheckName] = $form

}
*/

for(var cls in classRules) {
    var rule = classRules[cls];
    $.validator.addClassRules(cls, rule);
}

//return validationrules as rm.rules here

//in the caller, get validationrules from result
var editForm = $('#editForm')
.validate(
        {
            rules : rm.rules,
            classRules: rm.classRules,
            messages : rm.messages,
            success : $.noop
        });
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. It appears the validation has a preference for the first time it is being configured, thus ignoring my second validate command for the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Make the form's default action be prevent `e.preventDefault()`, then submit using `jQuery.ajax()`, choosing what `data` to send, then bind that `ajax` request to the form's `submit` button. Do this for each form:</s>

```
jQuery('.bidvalue').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: 'action=newbid&id='+e.target.name,
        success: function(msg){
            jQuery('#vehicle-value-box'+e.target.name).html(msg+',00€');
        }
});
```

**EDIT**, as I completely missed the actual question...

For each form, you can specify validation as below:

```
$('#myform1').validate({
    rules: {
        myfield1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        myfield2: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

but you'll have to be more specific and show the HTML of both forms, and maybe what validation rules you'd like, for me to really answer your question helpfully.

**EDIT #2**: To add some stuff form the comments (kudos to Vicente Olivert Riera for input).

If you wish to toggle which form to apply validation upon, do this:

```
var activeForm; 

$("form").focus(e => { 
    e.validate({
        rules: {
            myfield1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            myfield2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you have many forms and just want specific forms matching certain criteria only:

```
$("form").focus(e => { 
    // Some criteria to check against for the form.
    // Obviously you could make a crafty selector and avoid `if (e.hasClass())`, 
    // but this is to demonstrate using if to test the form if you wanted to check the form element in any way before applying `.validate()`.
    if (e.hasClass("someClass") { 
        e.validate(...);
    } 
});
```

Comment: And this relates to my question in which way?

Comment: ...Did you want to submit multiple forms on the same page?

Comment: No, i want to have one form active at a time, and having validation on the form fields is the tricky part.

Comment: Right, I see. Sorry, I didn't read it correctly. Let me have a think and edit my answer

Comment: @Adder Terribly sorry about the first answer, have a look at the edit and let me know if that's helpful in any way to you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. So are myfield1, myfield2 input field names or ids?

Comment: Can't you keep a variable indicating which form is currently active and depending on its value you perform the validation in the right form?

Comment: @Adder They are field names

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera You very well could do that too. To select depending on the active element's class name you could do: `var activeForm; $("form").focus(e => { activeForm = e; });`, and if you have many forms and just want `activeForm` to be specific forms only `$("form").focus(e => { if (e.hasClass("someClass") { activeForm = e; } });`